# Groovy/Grails caching on function/closure

Tags: caching, grails, groovy

I would like to know how to add caching capability to a groovy function.  Should it go in the Controller or the Service?  Example:  How would I cache **myService.getData()** result for 10 seconds?

```
class myController {
    def getDataAsJson {
        String result = myService.getData(id) // returns JSON
        render result
    }
}

class myService {
    def getData(String id) {
        return '{"hello":"world"}'
    }
}
```

I am using Grails 3.3.2 and Groovy 2.4.13.

Cheers!

Comment: Generally, you create a caching service. That way it can be used in other classes or functions. Take a look at how I created a caching service here: https://github.com/orubel/Beapi-API-Framework/blob/master/grails-app/services/net/nosegrind/apiframework/ApiCacheService.groovy

Comment: straight forward https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/cache